# Should I have the same Node in my local machine as the version of the environment I'm deploying to (ex: Firebase Cloud Functions)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, version

I'm working with React + Firebase.

And the only Node environment I'm currently deploying to is Firebase's Cloud Function environment. I'm using their Node 8 environment. Their Node 10 is still in Beta.

Should my local machine Node version match their environment? I.e: should I have Node 8 installed just because I'm deploying to a Node 8 environment?

Will it hurt anything if I have Node 12 on my PC? What are the downsides of that? What is the recommendation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use the same version so you can avoid having different issues on on your development environment and you production environment because of the different features available in different versions.

Easy way of having multiple versions of node installed on your local environment (plus you can change the default one at any time) is [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)